# how to use redux with routerWillLeave

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

So I have a setRouteleaveHook with function:

```
routerWillLeave(nextLocation) {
    // return false to prevent a transition w/o prompting the user,
    // or return a string to allow the user to decide:
    console.log("prompt: ", this.props.prompt);
    if (this.props.prompt) {
        return "Are you sure you wish to navigate? Unsaved data will be lost. Try to use the 'next' button instead if moving to the next part.";
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

`this.props.prompt` is a variable in the store. It seems that when I update it in it's parent, the `prompt` doesn't get altered until the next time I visit it.

Is there a better way to trigger these prompts? (Given that it is the parent component that is doing the `router.push`)

Answer (score 0):

import {withRouter} from 'react-router';

export default withRouter(connect(YourSelectors,YourActions)(YourPage))

Comment: this.props.router.setRouterLeaveHook(this.props.route,this.routerWillLeave)

Comment: My problem isn't getting the binding set up, I have that already. I just can't trigger the prompts correctly for my children. The receives the store changes correctly though.